# Wrapping server bootstrapper is deprecated, what is the alternative?

Tags: java, neo4j

The `WrappingNeoServer` instances (according to the manuals to the previous versions) have to be created via `WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper`, which is deprecated now. And if I try to instantiate `WrappingNeoServer` directly, I need to pass a `GraphDatabaseAPI` instance, which could be obtained by a simple cast of the `GraphDatabaseService`, but is marked as `Deprecated` as well.
I can only assume that this feature is now considered to be marginally necessary and there is no way to get an embedded installation running with the server no more. Am I right? Can this problem be solved in my favor?

Comment: Note that you should be careful using any of the classes from org.neo4j.server package - they should all be considered for internal use only. If you need REST based web access to Neo4j, or to use the Neo4j webadmin/browser, then please use Neo4j Server - downloadable from http://www.neo4j.com.

Comment: @ChrisLeishman, I needed exactly that: having running embedded app + web interface provided by the server. That was used for testing/debugging anyway, so won't be seen in the production code. Thanks for support though :)

Comment: ok, but please be aware that they may very well change or disappear in future releases.

Comment: @ChrisLeishman, that'd be very unfortunate. We currently use this configuration (embedded instance with webserver running inside it) in pre-production setups to monitor the behavior of the system and it helped us to find some pretty intricate bugs.

Comment: it would be interesting to hear more about that monitoring you're achieving via that setup. Those classes were never intended for that kind of use, so we don't want to be constrained to keep them. I would like to find another way to provide for what you're doing. If you feel like emailing me details, you can at my neotechnology.com address (chris.leishman at).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can override `CommunityNeoServer` and `CommunityServerBootstrapper` to do your bidding.

Comment: Note that both these classes should also be avoided, as they are not intended for external use. If one needs REST based web access to Neo4j, or to use the Neo4j webadmin/browser, then please use Neo4j Server - downloadable from http://www.neo4j.com

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem also with the actual version 2.0.3, and there is no CommunityNeoServer at the org.neo4j.server package